# Cannot read propery 'unsubscribe of undefined' on changing route

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

In my angular 2 app I have a parent component where I have made a subscription to a data source that passes this data down the line to multiple child components. In one of my child components I attempt to navigate to a different route in my app with parameters received from my subscription made in the top component. Whenever I do this in my app I get this error:

> Error in ./CompanyPromoCardComponent class CompanyPromoCardComponent -
>   inline template:6:10 caused by: Cannot read property 'unsubscribe' of
>   undefined

This is my: CompanyPromoCardComponent

```
export class CompanyPromoCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() company:Object;
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  gotoDetail(_id: String) {
    let link = ['/företag/' + _id + '/företagsinformation'];
    this.router.navigate(link);
  }

}
<div *ngIf="company">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <app-company-industry [company]='company' [sub]='sub'></app-company-industry>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <app-company-targetgroup [company]='company'></app-company-targetgroup>
        </div>
      </div>  
      <app-company-description [company]='company'></app-company-description>
      <app-company-tags [company]='company'></app-company-tags>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="gotoDetail(company._id)">Info</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my parent component where I subscribe to my data:

```
    export class SearchResultsComponent implements OnInit {

      companies:Array<Object>;
      user:Object;
      sub:any;
      constructor(
        private companyService:CompanyService, 
        private authService:AuthService,
        private flashMessage:FlashMessagesService
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.companyService.getCompaniesSearch().subscribe(data => {
          console.log('data.companies: ' + data.companies);
          this.companies = data.companies;
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
          return false;
        });
      }

      ngOnDestroy(){
        this.sub.unsubsribe();
      }

    }
```

company.industry component - child component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-company-industry',
  templateUrl: './company-industry.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-industry.component.css']
})
export class CompanyIndustryComponent implements OnInit {

  error: any;
  @Input() sub: any;
  navigated = false;
  @Input() company:Object;
  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.sub); 
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

What causes this error to occur? I simple want to navigate to another route that depends on the id returned from my company object.

Comment: So you don't use `unsubscribe` anywhere in your code?

Comment: I have tried to unsubscribe i my parent component OnDestroy without any luck but other than that I've yet to figure out how observables work so I don't understand where I how I'm supposed to unsubscribe.

Comment: Please include that part also since it is where the error occurs.

Comment: Updated with a simple ngOnDestroy() on the subscription that subscribes to the "company data".

Comment: you're setting the subscription for 'getCompaniesSearch' inside the subscription for 'getProfile'.  If the component gets destroyed before getProfile emits, the subscription will be undefined.

Comment: Could this has to do with my child components as well? I have multiple children as well that accepts data from my subscription as seen in the html snippet. How will these affect my subscription when I navigate away to another route? Should I unsubscribe the subscriptions in any particular order then?

Comment: @AntonScotte Are you sure that you're making the `getCompaniesSearch` call ?

Comment: Yes. The getCompaniesSearch() gets called and my data returns as expected, nothing fishy there. Also, when I removed the get profile subscription only for testing and subscribing to one data source only the problem still persists.

Comment: Essentially from what "think" I understand after tinkering around, I need to let the children components get the same subscription from the parent and when they are destroyed they should unsubscribe as well. Am I somewhat correct at all? I've updated my post to address these changes, though the subscription is still undefined.

Comment: @AntonScotte so what is `this.sub` in the child component? How does the child get this input?

Comment: My attempt on passing the subscription from the parent to the child the same way as I pass the company object, as you can see in the html snippet. **Although I feel like I'm beating around the bush here as I don't really understand what I'm doing at the moment!**

Comment: Whose html is that? If its `CompanyPromoCardComponent`'s html then it doesn't have a `sub` field.

Answer (score 0):

Its always a good practise to check if the variable is undefined or not before performing action as below,

```
ngOnDestroy(){
    if(this.sub){
         this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
```

How ever your problem is because `@input` variables are assigned through attributes. So, you can

```
this.companyService.getCompaniesSearch()
     .skipWhile(data => {
         return _.isEmpty(data);
      })
     .subscribe(data => {
          console.log('data.companies: ' + data.companies);
          this.companies = data.companies;
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
          return false;
        }).unsubscribe();
```

Note:

1. Adding a skip while makes you not subscribe till your data is available.
2. After completion of subscribing to the data you can unsubscribe() as above.